# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' while using re.replace

Tags: python, python-3.x

I do not really understand all this encode stuff. I am not sure how to solve the error below. Would really appreciate if someone could help me with this.

```
string = ' frame #0: [03m0x00067[0m embedded`excenerate_trap at [36mcpptions.c[0m:[36m398[0m:[33m3[0m [anu]!'

# print string
print('The string is:', string)

# ignore error
print('The encoded version (with ignore) is:', string.encode('utf-8'))

# replace error
string = string.encode("unicode_escape")

print('The encoded version (with replace) is:', string)

string = string.replace("'\\\\0", "'\\\\x00")
print("\n", string , "\n") 


ERROR that I get:
The string is:  frame #0: 0x00067 embedded`excenerate_trap at cpptions.c:398:3 [anu]!
The encoded version (with ignore) is: b' frame #0: \x1b[03m0x00067\x1b[0m embedded`excenerate_trap at \x1b[36mcpptions.c\x1b[0m:\x1b[36m398\x1b[0m:\x1b[33m3\x1b[0m [anu]!'
The encoded version (with replace) is: b' frame #0: \\x1b[03m0x00067\\x1b[0m embedded`excenerate_trap at \\x1b[36mcpptions.c\\x1b[0m:\\x1b[36m398\\x1b[0m:\\x1b[33m3\\x1b[0m [anu]!'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 15, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: You converted `string` to a byte string with `encode()`. So you have to use byte strings when you call `.replace()`

Comment: @Barmar, so instead of "'\\\\0" , I should give "b'\\\\x00" ?

Comment: No, `b` goes *before* the quote, not after it. `b"'\\\\0"`